# How can I display a smooth loading bar in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.7

I currently work on a game on pygame.
I want to create a loading window with a loading bar like the software GIMP but I really don't know how I can optimize that,... At all

So this is a part of my code, obviously, it's not working very well.
Can you help me?

```
...

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480), pygame.NOFRAME)
where = (120,360)
While in progress = true:
   If 1/a < 0.25
   screen.blit(Load0, where)
   If 1/a < 0.50
   screen.blit(Load1,where)
   #... ( it's the same for <0.75 and = 1 )
   pygame.display.update()
game()
```

But it's make a rellay bad loading bar...
Can you help me to make it really more optimized and smoother?
*PS : I got 350 elements to load*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simplify things, and draw a bar by 2 rectangles.

Create a function which draws a bar. The function draws a thin outer rectangle and filled inner rectangle. The length of the inner rectangle depends on the progress. `progress` is a value in  range [0, 1]. If it is 0, then no inner bar is draw. If it is 1, then the inner bar is complete:

```py
def DrawBar(pos, size, borderC, barC, progress):

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, borderC, (*pos, *size), 1)
    innerPos  = (pos[0]+3, pos[1]+3)
    innerSize = ((size[0]-6) * progress, size[1]-6)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, barC, (*innerPos, *innerSize))
```

Define the position and color parameters for the bar:

```py
barPos      = (120, 360)
barSize     = (200, 20)
borderColor = (0, 0, 0)
barColor    = (0, 128, 0)
```

Define the maximum number of items:

```py
max_a = 350
```

When you draw the bar, then the current progress is `a/max_a`:

```py
DrawBar(barPos, barSize, borderColor, barColor, a/max_a)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank, god, you're a genius

Comment: You have save my life, if you have time to help me to optimize the convertion of all picture ( my last new question ^^ ) it's will ne awesome ( you have already help me a lot, so you are not obligated ) :D